# OpenCV is not loading my webcam in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, opencv

I am just trying a simple OpenCV code test in PyCharm but every time I run the code it just ends. I know it is not an issue with my webcam as I have run the code using Anaconda's command prompt and it works though it does take some time to start up.

The code I am using is:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I feel that OpenCV is taking time to open up my webcam and so the first few reads are coming back as false and causing the code to end before my webcam can show but I don't know how to fix it. I tried googling around but I was not able to find anything. If anyone knows how I can fix this I would really appreciate your help!

Edit: nevermind I was being dumb. PyCharm was not executing the file I was on!

Comment: please run your code from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem is hardware related but, you can try something like this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    try:
        success, img = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception happened: {}".format(e))
        continue
```

This basically tries to execute the code inside of try and if an exception happens it executes the code inside of except. It also informs what the error is. You can also add some sleep using time.sleep(), before trying to read the webcam again.

For time.sleep(), you need to import time.

Hopefully this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your error can be from the your interpreter.Or you can try kick in your code and run it. Dont use the triangle symbol in the above right corner for the first attemp

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Mac, the PyCharm usually does not have access to webcam. So, its best you run your application from the terminal when you need to access the webcam.